# UIView animation side view slide from right to left after sliding from left to right in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am trying to make a side menu. I manage to find out how to slide to the right the mainview after using CGRectOffset and then adding another view on window and make it slide from left to right. It works but how can i make the mainview and the other view slide to left? Any help appreciated

```
- (IBAction)showsideview:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"sideview button pushed");
    
 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 243, 0);
       
        [ self.view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
              [ self.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
              [ self.view.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
              [ self.view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-2.0, -2.0)];
    }];
        
          sample = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"side"];
    
                  self->sample.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
   
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        
              [self.view.window addSubview:self->sample.view];
            
          
         }];
}
```

Comment: You would do it exactly the same way you just did it: set the frame in an animations block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation blocks in the same way. You can change the frame of the view within the UIView animation block.

```objectivec
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *sideView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

#pragma mark - Configure View

- (void)configureView {
    [self configureSideView];
}

- (void)configureSideView {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.sideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.sideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    button.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 100) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - 100) / 2, 100, 100);
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(sideViewButtonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.sideView addSubview:button];
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.sideView];
}

#pragma mark - Button Action

- (IBAction)mainViewButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.sideView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }];
}

- (void)sideViewButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.sideView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

@end
```

Use `Dot notation` rather than `Arrow operator` when accessing property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).